# Angular 8 Email validation throws exception

Tags: angular

I implemented the email validation through the tutorials. The problem is Email validation accepts something like "asd@asd" which is not a valid mail.

Secondly i get the error "ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.  Try using
      formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead. "
tried all the answers on stackoverflow but none of them worked.
What am i doing wrong ?

```
  this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email,
Validators.pattern('^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$')]],
        });
```

And the template :

```
 <input class="form-control" formControlName="email" type="text"[(ngModel)]="username" name="username" placeholder="E-mail"
               [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.email.errors }" />
        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.email.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
          <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.required">Email is required</div>
          <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.email">Email must be a valid email address</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: As already you're using `formControlName` in your `<input>` tag. Don't use `ngModel`

Comment: You shouldn't be using `ngModel` in form group. How ever if you want to use it for some reason, you have to declare it as a standalone. `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"`

Comment: [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" didnt change anything " Can't bind to 'ngModelOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'input'."

Comment: Like the first comment said. Either use ngModel or formcontrolname. I suggest the last option, as it is giving u much more options than simply bind to ngModel.

Comment: if i wont use ngModel , how would i reach the email value ? i tried  get email() {
    return this.loginForm.get('email');} but not working

Comment: You should be able to access it via `this.loginForm.controls.email.value` or `this.loginForm.controls['email'].value`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the `formControlName` directive alone to bind the email control.

```
<form [formGroup]= 'loginForm'> 
   <input id='email'  class="form-control" formControlName="email" 
        type="text" placeholder="E-mail" 
        [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && email.errors }" /> 
   <div *ngIf="submitted && email.errors" class="invalid-feedback"> 
       <div *ngIf="email.errors.required">Email is required</div>
       <div *ngIf="email.errors.email">
          Email must be a valid email address
       </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Alternatively, you can get the `control` instance using the `loginForm.get('email')` method and use the `loginForm.get('email').errors` object to display error messages.